# Does typescript need to be compiled to es6 and then to es5

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

Why does typescript need to be compiled to ES6 (or ES2015) at all ? As far as I can tell Typescript contains all the features that are present in ES6. So instead of compiling typescript code to ES6 and then using babel to compile ES6 code to ES5, why not just compile typescript code to ES5 directly. As far as i can tell compiling to ES6 simply adds an unnecessary compilation step.
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> Why not just compile typescript code to ES5 directly. As far as i can tell compiling to ES6 simply adds an unnecessary compilation step. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Indeed just using typescript alone would be *ideal* (and that is what I do). But if you want to use certain cutting edge ESNext features (e.g. async/await or generators) in browsers that don't support them natively (ES5 browsers) since TypeScript doesn't support transpiling them to ES5 (but will soon) you might need to use TypeScript + Babel.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript does support direct transpilation to `"ES3"` (default), `"ES5"`, `"ES6"`/`"ES2015"`, `"ES2016"`, `"ES2017"` or `"ESNext"`.

You can directly transpile to ES5 by specifying the `--target` flag as a [compilation option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

```
$ tsc --target ES5
```